# How do I get list of workspaces on monitor x with IndependentScreens

Tags: haskell, xmonad, xmonad-contrib

I've got 2 monitors of different sizes, one of witch is placed vertically, and I'd like them to have different layouts by default

I'm using `XMonad.Layout.IndependentScreens` to assign each monitor it's own set of workspaces

I have found a library that does approximately what I need `XMonad.Layout.PerWorkspace`

With that, I defined 2 monitor layouts that I will be using:

```
  where
     -- default tiling algorithm partitions the screen into two panes
     tiled   =  (Tall nmaster delta ratio) -- here, we can use `magicFocus`, but it creates several inconviniences

     -- The default number of windows in the master pane
     nmaster = 1

     -- Default proportion of screen occupied by master pane
     ratio   = 2/3

     -- Percent of screen to increment by when resizing panes
     delta   = 3/100

verticalLayout = Mirror tiled ||| tabbed shrinkText myTabConfig ||| noBorders Full  ||| tiled
  where
     -- default tiling algorithm partitions the screen into two panes
     tiled   =  (Tall nmaster delta ratio) -- here, we can use `magicFocus`, but it creates several inconviniences

     -- The default number of windows in the master pane
     nmaster = 1

     -- Default proportion of screen occupied by master pane
     ratio   = 2/3

     -- Percent of screen to increment by when resizing panes
     delta   = 3/100
```

So now I'm trying to use them on layout hook, together with workspacesOn function from IndependentScreens

```
        layoutHook         = smartBorders . avoidStruts $
            onWorkspaces (workspacesOn 0) myLayout $
            onWorkspaces (workspacesOn 1) verticalLayout
```

This fails with following error:

```
xmonad.hs:447:27: error:
    • Variable not in scope: workspacesOn :: Integer -> [WorkspaceId]
    • Perhaps you meant one of these:
        ‘workspaces'’ (imported from XMonad.Layout.IndependentScreens),
        ‘workspaces’ (imported from XMonad),
        ‘W.workspaces’ (imported from XMonad.StackSet)
    |
447 |             onWorkspaces (workspacesOn 0) myLayout $
    |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^

xmonad.hs:448:27: error:
    • Variable not in scope: workspacesOn :: Integer -> [WorkspaceId]
    • Perhaps you meant one of these:
        ‘workspaces'’ (imported from XMonad.Layout.IndependentScreens),
        ‘workspaces’ (imported from XMonad),
        ‘W.workspaces’ (imported from XMonad.StackSet)
    |
448 |             onWorkspaces (workspacesOn 1) verticalLayout
    |
```

Now I'm confused, because that function is in the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.17.0/docs/XMonad-Layout-IndependentScreens.html#v:workspacesOn), and I clearly included the reference to IndependantStreens, it's in the error message

What is the issue with the code above, and how do I get this to work?

Comment: What does `ghc-pkg list xmonad-contrib` say? (What version of `xmonad-contrib` do you have? Anyway, I don't think `workspacesOn` does what you think it does.

Comment: @DanielWagner it says " xmonad-contrib-0.16"

Comment: `workspacesOn` is new in 0.17. You can see the documentation for 0.16 [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.16/docs/XMonad-Layout-IndependentScreens.html). You can also reach this from the one you were looking at by clicking "Contents" in the top right, then on the version whose docs you want to see in the list to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your config, you have written something like:

```
workspaces = withScreens 2 ["a", "b", "c"]
```

You can get a list of the workspaces on a specific screen with [`marshall`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.17.0/docs/XMonad-Layout-IndependentScreens.html#v:marshall). The workspaces on screen 0 are `map (marshall 0) ["a", "b", "c"]` and similarly for screen 1. You should probably separate out the list of virtual workspaces into its own definition. So:

```
virtualWorkspaces = ["a", "b", "c"]

    ... (map (marshall 0) virtualWorkspaces) ...
    ... (map (marshall 1) virtualWorkspaces) ...

...
    workspaces = withScreens 2 virtualWorkspaces
```

Comment: I really need to learn Haskell